# How can I export each record from datalist c# asp.net to separate excelsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, export-to-excel, nested-datalist

please help me to export data from datalist webpage in asp.net c# to excel sheet which I want to export each record in separate sheet.
Note: I used Item template in datalist which appear as below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="dlstudent" runat="server" DataKeyField="STUDENT_ID"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="Black" />
        <HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="1"><tr style="background-color:Blue;color:White;">
         <td><b>Student Name</b> </td>
         <td>Student Address</td>
         <td>Student Class</td>
         </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="font-style:italic;">
          <td align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("STUDENT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="center"><asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("STUDENT_ADDRESS") %>'></asp:Label></td>
           <td align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblclass" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("STUDENT_CLASS") %>'></asp:Label></td>                  
        </ItemTemplate>          
                   </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestBlogConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [STUDENT_DETAIL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Export To Excel" />
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "StudentDetail.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter html = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        dlstudent.DataBind();
        dlstudent.RenderControl(html);
        Response.Write(writer.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.aspmantra.com/2013/07/how-to-export-datalist-data-to-excel.html